# Date filtering in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table below consists of 2 columns: a unique identifier and date.  I am trying to build a new column of episodes, where a new episode would be triggered when >= 3 months between dates. This process should occur for each unique EMID.  In the table attached, EMID ending in 98 would only have 1 episode, there are no intervals >2 months between each row in the date column.  However, EMID ending in 03 would have 2 episodes, as there is almost a 3 year gap between rows 12 and 13.  I have tried the following code, which doesn't work.

Table:

[image]

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [EMID],[Date]

CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(month, Date, LEAD Date) <3
     THEN "1"
     ELSE IF DATEDIFF(month, Date, LEAD Date) BETWEEN 3 AND 5
     THEN "2"
     ELSE "3"
END episode

FROM [res_treatment_escalation].[dbo].[cspine42920a]
```

EDIT: Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

EDIT 2: I have made some progress but the output is not exactly what I am looking for.  Here is the query I used:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [EMID],[visit_date_01],
CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, visit_date_01, LAG(visit_date_01,1,getdate()) OVER (partition by EMID order by EMID))  <= 90 THEN '1'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, visit_date_01, LAG(visit_date_01,1,getdate()) OVER (PARTITION BY EMID ORDER BY EMID)) BETWEEN 90 AND 179 THEN '2'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, visit_date_01, LAG(visit_date_01,1,getdate()) OVER (PARTITION BY EMID order by EMID)) > 180 THEN '3'
END AS EPISODE
FROM [res_treatment_escalation].[dbo].['c-spine_full_dataset_4#29#20_wi$']
```

[table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tILG5.png)Here is the actual vs expected output

The partition by EMID does not seem to be working correctly.  Every time there is a new EMID a new episode is triggered.   I am using day instead of month as the filter in DATEDIFF- this does not seem to recognize new episodes within the same EMID

Comment: show us your expected output in tabular form.

Comment: Hello Brian, there are many flavors of SQL could you please tag what DBMS you are using (SQL Server, Oracle, etc.)

Comment: `emid` is NOT a "unique identifier".  It is repeated on many rows.

Comment: You can't use whatever syntax you want, and expect sql server to understand it.  Have you checked documentation on how to use `LEAD`?

Comment: FYI: Management Studio is only a client interface, it is not the database engine. To get the version of your engine use `select @@version`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm:  Use `LAG()` to get the previous date.  Use a date comparison to assign a flag and then a cumulative sum:

```
select c.*,
       sum(case when prev_date > dateadd(month, -3, date) then 0 else 1 end) over
           (partition by emid order by date) as episode_number
from (select c.*, lag(date) over (partition by emid order by date) as prev_date
      from res_treatment_escalation.dbo.cspine42920a c
     ) c;
```